# Следует ли при проектировании базы в mongo разделять сущности или делать это через композицию?

Tags: mongodb, база-данных

Простой пример - форум без сложной структуры. Есть "Тема" и есть "Ответы".

- Должно ли быть две коллекции, со связью один ко многим где "*Ответы*" ссылаются на "*Вопрос*"? (Реляционный подход)
- Или добавлять ответы в массив "*Ответов*" для каждого вопроса (композиция)
- Или сделать одну коллекцию (т.к. *тикет* от *ответа* отличается мало, то считать их одной сущностью) с разницей, что у *ответов* будет ссылка на *вопрос*? (Эдакий реляционных подход со связью внутри своей коллекции)

Например второй метод ставит  для меня вопрос: будет ли это удобно когда я захочу найти вопрос по *id*.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исходя из изученного материала и общения на эту тему дам ответ на свой вопрос.

Зависит от того как будут использоваться сущности. Т.е. если нам не нужно будет искать ответы по id или другому признаку то необходимо отдельная схема т.к. доступ в этом случае будет невозможен.

*Причина непонимания была в том, что мною предполагалось, что даже в случае добавления массива в запись будет происходить его индексация.*

Comment: даже в случае добавления массива в запись будет происходить его индексация. - Djn вот это не совсем понятно. Разве монго не индексирует поля - массивы?